# Retrieving data from Firebase in Android activity

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I read many threads regarding how to get data from Firebase database instance, but none of them worked for me.

My code in the activity:

```
public class Violations extends AppCompatActivity
{
TextView textView7;

FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference dbref = database.getReference("save");

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_violations);

    textView7 = findViewById(R.id.textView7);

    dbref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener()
    {
        ArrayList<String> Violations = new ArrayList<>();
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
        {
            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren())
            {
                Violations.add(postSnapshot.getValue().toString());
                System.out.println(postSnapshot.getValue().toString());
            }
            for(int i=0; i < Violations.size(); i++)
            {
                textView7.setText(textView7.getText() + Violations.get(i) + System.lineSeparator());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
    });
}
}
```

There is no error in there, but no data displays. I am pretty sure, my problem is connecting to the right instance and retrieving the data.

Firebase data, are like this:

[image]

Can someone please help me in there?

Thanks you in advance.

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint in `onDataChange()` to check if it triggers ? Besides that, you should take a look at [How to denormalize data in Firebase](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2013/04/denormalizing-your-data-is-normal.html) because you will really have some troubles if you keep this exact structure for your database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `addListenerForSingleValue()` instead of `addValueEventListener()`. Hope it helps. And change your firebase link `save` to `you violate your own speed limit with`

Comment: The problem was in the firebase link. So this fixed the issue. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Initialize the Firebase database & the `DatabaseReference` inside `onCreate()` method:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_violations);

    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference dbref = database.getReference("save");

    ...
    ..
```

Also, the reference you are getting is `save` but the Firebase database shows that is : `you violate ...`. You may try changing the name to `save` or getting the right data : `you violate ...`.

Comment: The initialization is not the issue (I checked). The issue was in the firebase link.

Comment: Well yeah, if you want to get all the data, you can use `addValueEventListener()` (As your requirements) but however, I didn't see `save` child in the database and that was weird.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot see in your database schema o reference named `save` but I see one named `You violate your own speed limit with`, which mush be used in your reference in order to be able to get data from the database. So to solve this, please use the following lines of code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference ref = rootRef.child("You violate your own speed limit with");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        ArrayList<String> violations = new ArrayList<>();
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String speed = ds.getValue(String.class);
            violations.add(speed);
            Log.d(TAG, speed);
        }

        //Do what you need to do with y our violations list
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage());
    }
};
ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

The result in your logcat will be all those values:

```
3 km / h at time: ...
3 km / h at time: ...
//an so on
```